# Automatic <pre> padding-left

Tags: css, sass

Having some problems styling `<pre>` tags today.

```
<div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
    <pre>
        .wrapper {
            width: 100%;
            color: $orange;
        }
    </pre> 
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

pre {
    @include mono;
    color: $light-grey;
    background-color: $orange;
    padding-top: 1em;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
    width: 585px;
    @include box-sizing(border-box);
}
```

The SCSS variables and mixins are all self explanatory. This is the output:

[image]

The orange box is the `<pre>`, beige box is `<div class="content">`, and outer orange box the `<body>`.

I have no idea why this behaviour is present. There is NO padding applied at all.

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are seeing the white space in your HTML source file... you would need to strip it out (in a smart way) before echoing your code snippet in the `<pre>` tag.

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/teYjW/